# Time Dependent Perturbation Theory Probabilities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, approximations

(This is taken from Griffiths Quantum Mechanics):
So suppose I have two states $\psi_{a}$ and $\psi_{b}$, and the particle starts out in the state $\psi_{a}$:
$$
c_{a}(0)=1\qquad c_{b}(0)=0.
$$

To first order,
$$
c_{a}^{(1)}(t)=1\qquad c_{b}^{(1)}(t)=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{0}^{t}H_{ba}'(t')e^{i\omega_{0}t'}dt'
$$
where
$$
H_{ba}'=\left<\psi_{b}|H'|\psi_{a}\right>
$$
for some perturbation $H'(t)$.

Now the probabilities $$|c_{a}^{(1)}(t)|^2+|c_{b}^{(1)}(t)|^2\neq 1.$$ Griffiths says that to first order in $H'$, these sum to 1. I'm just not quite sure how to make sense of this statement. Do I do some kind of expansion in $H'$ and show that $|c^{(1)}_{b}(t)|^2$ vanishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, to the 1st order, the sum is 1.

Note that $|c_b(t)|^2$ is on the 2nd order of the perturbation.